# Show recent posts within Wordpress bootstrap Dropdown menu

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I created a custom bootstrap Navwalker class for my WordPress theme. All things work correctly with this code below. I put this code within `function start_el(){}`:

```
if (!empty($item->divideto_4)) {
    $col = 3;
    $divide_to = 12 / $col; //4

    for ($i=0; $i<$divide_to; $i++) {
        $item_output .= '<div class="col-sm-'.$col.'">'.get_the_title().'</div>';
    }
}
```

**My Problem:** The code duplicates the last post four times and does not show  the last four posts. I want it to show me the most recent four posts. How can I do this?

Comment: Take a look at the [`get_the_title()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title) function.

Comment: Problem in the `for` loop not in `get_the_title()` function

Comment: no its get_the_title, you need to pass the id of the post you want unless you want the current posts title.

Comment: Did you check the documentation for `get_the_title()` function from the link given above?

Comment: Yes i checked the `get_the_title()` but i say only show last posts no last four recent posts

Comment: Did you notice that the `get_the_title()` function has an argument called $ID?

Comment: I know i solved my problem today i used WP_Query loop instead for loop now return all posts